# Tomcat 403 error calling '/' in Grails app

Tags: tomcat, grails

This must be a very simple issue but I can't work it out. I've deployed a Grails 2.2.5 application, which has been working successfully under Tomcat 6, to Tomcat 7, and everything works fine except for the root URL, which gives a 403 error. E.g., '/myapp/booking/list' works just fine, but '/myapp/' gives the error. There have been no changes in the code or configuration from the web application which is working 100% OK on Tomcat 6. I'm a bit puzzled.

Comment: check your `UrlMappings.groovy` if it has some conflicting stuff

Comment: As I said, the application is a direct copy of one working successfully on Tomcat 6, where the UrlMappings.groovy clearly works successfully. This problem has occurred without any changes in code or configuration, which is what is puzzling me. Presumably some environment thing, but what? LATER: See answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer turned out to be operator error in a way that having the question around will really never be helpful to anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

As ever, turned out to be a bit of stupidity on my part. On looking into the code again, I realised that I was actually calling an action in a HomeController.groovy, which checked for a specific string in the host and returned a 403 if it didn't find it. Duh!